# Functions that intake an object that inherits x class

Tags: c++, inheritance

if I were to make a base class:

```
     class Father
     {
       public:
       void doSomething();
     };
```

and then if I were to make these classes:

```
     class Daughter : public Father
     {

     };
     class Son : public Father
     {

     };
```

could I have a function that intakes an object and executes its `doSomething()`

```
     void function(const &Father thing)
     {
         thing.doSomething
     }
     int main()
     {
         Son son();
         Daughter daughter();
         function(son);
         function(daughter);
     }
```

Comment: Yes. In fact except for your decleration of `function` everything here would work. What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, since `doSomehing()` is inherited by `Son` and `Daughter`. However the `Father::doSomething()` will be executed. If you mark `Father::doSomething()` as `virtual`, then override it in `Daughter` and `Son`, then you achieve runtime polymorphism, i.e. the "right" function is called, based on the type of the instance. Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Father
{
public:
    virtual void doSomething() const {std::cout << "Father\n";}
    virtual ~Father() = default;
};

class Daughter : public Father
{
    void doSomething() const override {std::cout << "Daughter\n";}
};

class Son : public Father
{
    void doSomething() const override {std::cout << "Son\n";}
};

void function(const Father& thing)
{
    thing.doSomething();
}

int main()
{
    Son son;
    Daughter daughter;
    function(son);
    function(daughter);
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/578c6649e0d3e75c)

Note: you have lots of typos in your code. A more serious error is that your `doSomething()` is not marked `const`, hence you won't be able to call it from a `const` reference.